# Convert dtype "object" to whatever Excel needs to identify date column and time column

Tags: python, excel, pandas, datetime

I have a dataframe and set the datetime column to index. When I extract the date and time for the date column and time column via `data.insert(loc=0, column="Uhrzeit", value=data.index.time)` and `data.insert(loc=0, column="Datum", value=data.index.date)` the columns are object.

when I save that to excel with `pd.to_excel` the time column is probably saved as text (excel imports it as text) and so I can't perform operations on it in excel. (Changing the format in Excel to "time" does nothing.) The date column is identified as date by excel.

So how do I change the dtypes of the columns so that excel can identify them as "date" and "time"? The time column may only display time, the date column only date. Keeping them togehter in one datetime-column is not an option.

```
                          Datum   Uhrzeit    Temp
Datum/Uhrzeit                                    
2019-07-22 13:45:00  2019-07-22  13:45:00  12.247
2019-07-22 16:45:00  2019-07-22  16:45:00  12.251
2019-07-22 19:45:00  2019-07-22  19:45:00  12.247
2019-07-22 22:45:00  2019-07-22  22:45:00  12.251
2019-07-23 01:45:00  2019-07-23  01:45:00  12.255

>>> data.dtypes
Temp        float64
Uhrzeit      object
Datum        object
dtype: object
```

trying `data['Uhrzeit'] = [dt.datetime.strptime(d, "%H:%M:%S") for d in data['Uhrzeit']]` gives this error:

`TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not datetime.time`

Comment: In excel, you need to apply `format cell` then appropriate formatting to the cells then it will work fine.

Comment: As i said: Changing the format in Excel to "time" does nothing.

Comment: did you try to leave the datetime index as it is, i.e. just `value=data.index`?

Comment: Excel times are always datetimes. They are just normally formatted to exclude the date portion if the date portion is equivalent to 0. Datetimes are stored as the number of days since 1900-01-01, with times as a decimal fraction of a day.

Comment: @MrFuppes: do you mean in the `data.insert()`? That would cause having the same data in index, date column and time column. Also I would have time and date in date column and date and time in time column, which I don't want. The time column may only display time, the date column only date.

Comment: @vossa yes it does, I just did. It is working fine

Comment: You need to format the cell as `Time` as 'hh:mm:ss

Comment: check this https://imgur.com/ZvGrlTs and thus https://imgur.com/iJuKahZ

Comment: @Epsi95: I change the format of the cell and nothing happens. When I then click into the cell and press enter, the format ist applied. Yes, that works, but the file hast 8459 rows, I can't do that for every cell.

Comment: there are many ways to do that. You select the cell and click format painter. Then you just paint the remaining cell. Ideally, you should select all the column by `ctrl+shift+down arrow` then apply the format

Comment: that's exactly what I did `ctrl+shift+down arrow` then apply the format and nothing happens, only after klicking into one cell an press enter. then the format of that cell changed.

Comment: Isn't here a way to define the format before or while saving to xlsx?